# How can i drag text from one place to another place in iPad

Tags: iphone

user can write text by using keyboard in ipad.

After he can able to drag that text from one place to another place.
is it possible?

please help me .

thank you in-advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move the entire text field, then you can use this code:

Note you must declare a boolean like userIsTouching in your header

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Check if the user's touch is within the textfield
    CGPoint touch = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(textField.frame, touch)) {
        userIsTouching = YES;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (userIsTouching) {
        textField.center = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    }
}

// Obviously, you then have to set the userIsTouching variable to NO when the user releases the touch

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    userIsTouching = NO;
}
```

Something like that should do it.